# How to pass a value from handler to aspx page as a response

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, uploadify

I am adding the file name as the response in the handler, and in my JavaScript I am trying to get the value that I added in the handler and save that to a hidden field. The hidden field value however is always null. I am not getting the file name that I add  to the response. How do I get the filename as response from handler

```
public class Upload : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState   
{    
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
    {
        context.Response.Write(filename);
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    }
}


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=AFU_Video.ClientID%>").uploadify({
                'uploader': 'scripts/uploadify.swf',
                'script': 'Upload.ashx',
                'buttonText': 'Video',
                'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
                'folder': 'D:\Media',
                'fileExt': '*.mp4',
                'fileDesc': 'Video Files (.mp4 Only)',
                'multi': true,
                'auto': true,
                'onComplete': function (event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
                    document.getElementById("<%= Hidd_VideoLoc.ClientID %>").value = response.filename;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use the `filename` property of the response object, but as you are returning plain text there is no such property.

Just use the response:

```
document.getElementById("<%= Hidd_VideoLoc.ClientID %>").value = response;
```